# Size of bit-field union which has more members than its size

Tags: c, unions

```
#include <stdio.h>

union mix {
  unsigned char a1:1;  
  unsigned char a2:4;
  unsigned char a3:4;    
  unsigned char a4:1;  
  unsigned char a5:4;
  unsigned char a6:4;    
  unsigned char a7:1;  
  unsigned char a8:4;
  unsigned char a9:4;    
  unsigned char a10:1;  
  unsigned char a11:4;
  unsigned char a12:4;       
};

int main() {

    printf("Sizeof mix = %d bytes\n", sizeof(union mix));

    return 0;
}
```

The output is **1 byte**.

What happens to bit-field members which exceed 8 bits ? Apparently I can still set and get correct values for any bit-field member.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for clearing my confusion. One side question: in what order do the bits get stored in memory ? Assuming it is little endian memory so 0xabcd will be stored in memory as 0xd, 0xc, 0xb, 0xa.

1. Will m.a1 be part of 0xd OR oxa?
2. Will it be bit 3 or bit 0 of 0xd(or 0xa)?

Comment: There are no members with more than 8 bits. `union` != `struct`.

Comment: @tkausl  got it.. I got confused by mixing struct/union/bit-fields.. :) thanks.

Comment: You seem to be confusing size of union with size of union member. Generally, size of union equals to the size of its largest member - in this case it's one byte, because all the members are chars (rounded to byte-size, because it's the minimal unit of actual size)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@tkausl is correct.  In a `union`, each member overlaps with all the other members in memory.  Therefore, each field in the bitfield overlaps with the others depending on the number of bits in each field and the endianness of the platform.  For example, `a1` and `a10` probably always have the same value.

Since all the fields are overlapped in memory, you only need as many bytes as are required to hold the *longest* field.  Since one byte will do it, that's the size of the `union`.

Answer (score 3):

*in what order do the bits get stored in memory ?*

That is **implementation-defined.**

Per **6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**, paragraph 11 of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large
>   enough to hold a bit- field.  If enough space remains, a bit-field
>   that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be
>   packed into adjacent bits of the same unit.  If insufficient space
>   remains, whether  a  bit-field  that  does  not  fit  is  put  into 
>   the  next  unit  or  overlaps  adjacent  units  is
>   implementation-defined.  **The order of allocation of bit-fields
>   within a unit (high-order to low-order  or  low-order  to  high-order)
>   is  implementation-defined.**  The  alignment  of  the addressable
>   storage unit is unspecified.

Different compilers can implement bit-fields differently.  Note that high-order and low-order is not the same as big-endian or little-endian.  The low-order bit of an 8-bit `unsigned char` is the one that adds `1` to it's value when it's flipped on and off.  The high-order bit of the same 8-bit `unsigned char` is the one that adds 128 to its value when it's flipped on.

So bit-fields have two levels of implementation-defined order:  platform/hardware defined endianness and compiler defined high- or low-order assignment.  You can also the padding between bit fields and whether or not they span adjacent units to the implementation-defined specifics of bit-fields.